# How can I get the lookup_field value in My Update APIView?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

How can I get the lookup_field value in My Update APIView?

the bellow is my code:

```
class UserAdminDeleteAPIView(RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    model = User
    serializer_class = UserAdminSerializer
    permission_classes = []
    lookup_field = "username"

    def get_object(self, queryset=None): 
        username = self.request.data.get('username')  # there I get None
        obj = User.objects.get(username=username)
        return obj
```

When I access the API by `localhost:8000/api/users/user10/delete`, I can not get the username(`user10`).

How can I get the `username` param?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access url's kwargs inside class based view using [`self.kwargs`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#dynamic-filtering) attribute:

```
def get_object(self, queryset=None): 
    username = self.kwargs.get('username')
    obj = User.objects.get(username=username)
    return obj
```

Note in url pattern you should use `username` as arg name:

```
url(r'^articles/(?P<username>\w+)/$', UserAdminDeleteAPIView.as_view()),
```